# Is it prohibited to ride public transport that also operates on Shabbat

Tags: shabbat, vehicles-transportation

In Israel, most public transport shuts down on Shabbat.

If it did operate on Sabbath, perhaps by non Jews, would it be permissable for Jews to use it on weekdays?

Comment: ripper234, welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for bringing your question here!

Comment: Your question would be improved if you would state why you think it might be forbidden.

Comment: @msh210 Because I assume there is _some_ reason public transport shuts down (it is definitely 'because' of some Jewish people)...

Comment: @Isaac - thanks! I'm rather curious what would the answer/s be.

Comment: Regular Egged bus lines run (at a reduced frequency) in Haifa and Eilat. The drivers include both Jews and Arabs.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12331/riding-the-subway-on-shabbat

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not see why it would be not permissible to use it. No one has a problem using electricity during the week, which the electric company is operating on Shabbos too. No one has a problem using the telephone during the week, which the phone company is operating on Shabbos.

The only possible reason that some people might have not to use it during the week, is that they feel that by not using it during the week, it would make the company not run on Shabbos.

Comment: This is also similar to what happened to El Al when they started flying on Shabbos. The power of the masses can change things...

Comment: Do you by any chance have a reference for that?

Comment: @ripper234 are you asking me or Gershon?

Comment: @yydl - I'm asking Gershon.