Why is prohibited to sit in a moving car on Shabbat
I have heard that there is a prohibition on riding in a car on Shabbat, what is the work being done by doing so?

https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/6612 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/79588/catching-a-bus-on-shabbes

Ok, I think I understand now.
